# Setting up CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Rackspace Cloud Files?

Tags: apache, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

Can anyone provide any insight into how CORS works on Rackspace Cloud Files?

I tried setting the value of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the url of my webserver but I can still access the public url of the object by just pasting it into a browser.

Maybe I misunderstand how CORS works? Setting the access control allow origin to my web server would only allow the file to be accessed from the web server. Me, as a user pasting the url into the web browser, would be from a different origin, no ?

The documentation at Rackspace isn't the best sometimes for stuff like this (or I'm looking in the wrong place...)

Answer (score 1):

That's not really what CORS is for. Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows Javascript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain, not the domain the Javascript originated from, see [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

It has nothing to do with making an object or container public/private.

On Rackspace, CORS works according to this [doc](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/CORS_Container_Header-d1e1300.html).